# Why is interest on MMA lower in the US than in Europe?

Tags: interest-rate

Looking at [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/what-is-the-best-way-to-invest-short-term-without-losing-principal), my first thought was "just use a [MMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_market_account) with [> 2%](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://www.tagesgeldvergleich.net/tagesgeldvergleich/&prev=_t&rurl=translate.google.com&twu=1&usg=ALkJrhh20_ZXsgPiqZE699KL-giTw40CGw)". The Bank of Scotland offers 2.3% right now.

The answers showed some ways with way under 2%, so I figured something had to be wrong. Looking up US MMAs, I typically found only around 1%, which is dramatically lower.

The only reason I could think of is the FED's prime rate is only 0 - 0.25 while ECB's is 1.25. Did I miss something?

Additionally, is there a good way for an investor as in the linked question (6-9 month) to still profit from Europe's higher interest rates? I could imagine exchanging USD to EUR and back easily eats up all gain.

Answer (score 2):

I think you answered yourself. The rate difference is because of the base rates differences, and it's not worth moving money around because the rate conversions (even if the currency rates don't fluctuate) will eat up the difference.