# Short term investments

Tags: certificate-of-deposit

I have saved money, but haven't been investing it. Don't know where to start. House is payed for, little to no debt. Only making 58k a year.
Are CD's the best low risk short term option?

Comment: There are a few similar questions on the site, but the answers depend on your needs, what's the reason for needing it to be short-term, and how short are you thinking? Do you need access to some of it periodically or comfortable/prefer to lock it away?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to invest short term without losing principal?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/what-is-the-best-way-to-invest-short-term-without-losing-principal)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CDs are great if you select the right one. Both Chase and Bank of America offer CDs ranging from 3.5 to 4.5% APR. However, some CDs from them have very low interest rates, like 0.5%, so you should be careful.
The other low-risk short-term option would be to lend your money to a trusted borrower.

Comment: Note that right now, some banks are offering "bonus rates" if you open a CD with "new money" (that is, money which wasn't already in that bank). My credit union had an offer of 5% APR on a 6-month CD opened this way.